# Get different objects out of in64 data type return

Tags: python, pandas, format

As part of a big function I am stuck with one of the last lines. 
I should get the row and column name of the highest (few) value(s) in a (pandas) data frame. Therefor I unstacked it, sorted it and printed the last 2 lines. using:

```
df2=zerotriangle_frame.unstack()
sorted_df = df2.sort_values(inplace=True)
x = df2[-2:]
```

this resulted in:

```
seq_6120  seq_1761    34
seq_4833  seq_1761    37
dtype: int64
```

This is good (respectively: seq_4833  and seq_1761 are row and column name resembling highest value (highest sequence simmilarity in context) in dataframe, seq_6120 and seq_1761 resembling the second highest value...)  but i want to somehow format this output so that I can use the different parts in a print section. for example:

```
print("sequenc {0} and sequence {1} got the highest simmilarity value:{2}".format(a, b, c))
```

where a, b and c should be seq_4833, seq_1761 and 37 respectively... 
If the outcome was a list or tuple I could split it, but now I'm stuck.

PS: Also, when the values (34 and 37 in example) are the same I should print some specific error message (like 'more than 1 pair of sequences with same simmilarity').

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming df2 is your final dataframe then you can just filter for all the rows that equal to the max value and write an if statement to produce the output.

```
# assuming df2 is a dataframe with columns a,b,c
df3 = df2[df2.c == df2.c.max()]

if len(df3) == 1:
    print("sequence {0} and sequence {1} got the highest simmilarity value:{2}".format(df3.a.values[0], df3.b.values[0], df3.c.values[0]))
else:
    for i, row in df3.iterrows():
        print("sequence {0} and sequence {1} got the same simmilarity value:{2}".format(row.a, row.b, row.c))
```

Comment: I cannot make my result into a dataframe with column names a, b and c... So what you see in my question is x. If I want to turn this into a data frame I do: df2=pd.DataFrame(x, columns=['a','b','c'] but that does not work

Comment: X is a series. Do x.reset_index() And then you will have a dataframe.

Comment: How should I implement a for loop that gives the similarity value and every pair of sequences that have this maximum value if there are more than one pair? So instead of printing 'more than 1 pair of Sequences with same similarity', I should print all the pairs...

Comment: @H.F.SC. You can use `iterrows` to loop through and print all values. Check updated solution. Check the answer as good if it helped you.

Comment: thank you very much! I got itnow! My function is complete. Since I was unfamiliar with pandas DataFrame, I had these questions.

Comment: No problem. Feel free to accept the answer by clicking the check mark below the vote buttons on my answer.